# Bluemix Apache Spark Metrics

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I have been looking for a way to monitor performance in Spark on Bluemix. I know in the Apache Spark project, they provide a metrics service based on the Coda Hale Metrics Library. This allows users to report Spark metrics to a variety of sinks including HTTP, JMX, and CSV files. Details here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html

Does anyone know of any way to do this in the Bluemix Spark service? Ideally, I would like to save the metrics to a csv file in Object Storage.

Appreciate the help.

Thanks

Saul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, I do not see an option for usage of "Coda Hale Metrics Library" and reporting the job history or accessing the information via REST API.

However, on the main page of the Spark history server, you can see the **Event log directory**. It refers to your following user directory: file:/gpfs/fs01/user/USER_ID/events/

There I saw JSON (like) formatted files.

Comment: Yes I saw some things in the Spark history server. Can I access this JSON data through my browser?

Comment: The JSON files should reflect the same data you can access via the Spark history server link in the side panel. By "..through my browser" you mean download ?

Comment: I realize that in order to access data through the browser or via curl or other methods, there would have to be a rest-api, which there is not.The event log directory is set to /gpfs/fs01/user/USER-ID/events. If this is like open source spark, it means that there is an event log in that directory. What I mean is, can I get access to that log?

Comment: I have just realized that this directory is present in the Spark history server and contains some details on all the jobs that I have run. So no need to answer that question. Thanks